# Why is the constant `fabletools` different from the mean in `forecast` package (ARIMA model)?

Tags: r, forecast, fable

I started rewriting all my code from forecast to fable. 
Does anybody know why the constant is different from the mean?

```
library("fable")
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("forecast")

# gen data
set.seed(68)
df <- data.frame(time = ymd(Sys.Date() - c(1:1000)),
                 V = rnorm(1000, 0.2))
df <- fabletools::as_tsibble(df, index = time, regular = TRUE) %>% dplyr::arrange(time)

# fable model
df %>% fabletools::model(fable::ARIMA(V ~ pdq(3, 0, 0) + PDQ(0, 0, 0))) %>% report()

# forecast model
as.ts(df) %>% forecast::Arima(c(3, 0, 0), include.mean = TRUE)
```

## fable model

```
Series: V 
Model: ARIMA(3,0,0) w/ mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ar3  constant
      -0.0578  -0.0335  -0.0158    0.2141
s.e.   0.0316   0.0317   0.0317    0.0308

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9499:  log likelihood=-1391.23
AIC=2792.45   AICc=2792.51   BIC=2816.99
```

## forecast model

```
Series: . 
ARIMA(3,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ar3    mean
      -0.0578  -0.0335  -0.0158  0.1934
s.e.   0.0316   0.0317   0.0317  0.0278

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9499:  log likelihood=-1391.23
AIC=2792.45   AICc=2792.51   BIC=2816.99
```

and I get for some higher order models following error, which I can't interpret properly. 
I am able to estimate the models with `forecast`, even though the models might be silly, I can't even estimate them with `fable`

```
Warning message: 
1 error encountered for ar
[1] There are no ARIMA models to choose from after imposing the `order_constraint`, please consider allowing more models.`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models that you are specifying between fable and forecast are equivalent.
The parameterisation between the packages differ, `fable::ARIMA` uses constant form whereas `forecast::Arima` and `stats::arima` use mean form.

This is discussed in https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html#understanding-constants-in-r

---

Furthermore, in your fable model specification you have not specified if the constant (or equivalently, the `include.mean`) in the model. If this is not done, fable will automatically select between including and excluding the constant via an algorithm similar to `auto.arima`. You should add `1` (include) or `0` (exclude) to your formula to specify the model's constant.

`fable::ARIMA(V ~ 1 + pdq(3, 0, 0) + PDQ(0, 0, 0)))` is equivalent to `forecast::Arima(V, c(3, 0, 0), include.mean = TRUE)`.

This is also why you're having trouble with estimating higher order models. When automatically selecting a model, `fable::ARIMA` will respect the argument `order_constraint = p + q + P + Q <= 6`. As the constant is not specified (and will be automatically selected), this order constraint is being enforced (giving no possible models to evaluate). You can keep automatic selection by removing the `order_constraint` with `order_constraint = TRUE` (this means that whenever testing the constraint, it will be TRUE, i.e. acceptable).

I have updated the package to include more informative errors and a better description of the parameterisation in `?ARIMA`.